# How to output JS and CSS files in vite during development mode

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, vite

I'm currently running react, during development, to output the bundled JS and CSS into a file which is read by a layout in ASP.NET (using webpack). The build version also works in a similar way, outputting the files which are deployed to a server and referenced from the layout.

I want to upgrade to Vite to get all the benefits, I have the build version running and the files being loaded into the MVC site where I want them. But during development mode, I cannot find any information on how to do this

My folder structure is a standard ASP.NET app with a web project and a content folder. Inside there I have my current react project and during development, the files get outputted to content/dist. This is imported in the layout file and I have a `div` which has the `#root` ID. This all works with webpack but the dev mode is so slow (I'm talking 30+ seconds to boot)

Is there a way to achieve this setup in Vite.js?